# Highlight Specific Word in Associated String and String Variable in Tableau

Tags: nlp, data-visualization, tableau-api

My goal is to create a highlight function for keywords contained within an associated string, and the overall string variable.

After trying "contains" function, trying variations of the logic contained in these links (1st - https://community.tableau.com/thread/214410, 2nd - https://community.tableau.com/message/846896#846896), and receiving an answer from Tableau Support that they don't know how to highlight keywords contained therein, I wanted to try the Stack OverFlow community before giving up on this one.

To illustrate, below is a table showing my goal with a matrix that contains a keyword and an associated string:

[image]

The next shows the ability to select a keyword that is then highlighted within all observations in the string variable:

[image]

The closest I have achieved is the following where only the associated string and its entirety are highlighted, as opposed to the broader string variable and just the keyword within the relevant string:

[image]

The logic is the following:

*Create a parameter for users to enter their search keyword, and create a calculated field to see if the keyword is contained in the Comment field
Create and show a Highlighter for the Comment field.*

*To use a parameter to call attention to the comment using color:
Create a Parameter called "Search Keyword" with data type string. Select "All" for allowable values.
Create a calculated field called Matches or Color Matches, with the following formula:*

```
CONTAINS([Key Words], [Search Keywords])
OR CONTAINS([Comments], [Search Keywords])
```

*Drag this calculated field onto Color on the Marks card
Right-click the parameter and select "Show Parameter Control
Type the keyword to search and highlight.*

*To use a Highlighter:
Once the dashboard with keywords and comments has been created, navigate to the options menu for the Comments sheet and select Highlighters > Comments
This now displays a Highlight control which will highlight the row of a comment, instead of changing the text color like the parameter does.
This option will also allow for clicking on keywords, but clicking will only highlight the corresponding comment rather than all comments with the keyword.*

*As a potential third alternative, if viewers only want to see the matching words and not the entire string, we can modify the parameter method to add an IF statement to the calculated field we created earlier:*

```
IF CONTAINS([Key Words], [Search Keywords])
OR CONTAINS([Comments], [Search Keywords])
THEN [Search Keywords]
END
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to tweak what I have, or even take a different approach? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your problem is that, to highlight *words* in a sentence, you need the words to be addressible as a Tableau variable not whole strings. This is quite doable but requires you to restructure the raw data to separate strings into their component words (and group them to make sentences). This isn't that hard as [this Tableau Public viz of the text of the King James Bible illustrates](https://public.tableau.com/views/KingJamesBiblev2_5/wordclouddash?:display_count=y&:origin=viz_share_link).

Comment: Very useful reference. I appreciate the comment and link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am sure you know, Tableau is going to colour the entire text string as the CONTAINS condition results in TRUE for the entire string. A different approach could be to restructure your data to a 'long' format with 1 row per word (as below).

[image: Example Data Structure]

Doing this will ensure that Tableau knows each word should be evaluated separately and that the Color Marks Card will partition each word. You can then structure your worksheet like this. To ensure the words are showing in the correct order, you'll need a calculated field to create a unique row (I have called sort_order `right("000000" + str([sentence_id]),7)  + right("000000" + str([Position]), 7)`. Note that the Text Marks Card is sorted by sort_order and also that the order in which you drag on/order the Mark Cards is important

[image: Tableau Example]

The colour_keyword formula then is simply something like `[word] = [Keyword Parameter]` (maybe check for upper/lowercase variants).

I would recommend maintaining your original table's data structure as well as this 'long table format and link the two datasources via a Relationship (Data > Edit Relationships) and use Dashboard Actions. This would hopefully satisfy your highlight requirements and mean less rework for your other worksheets.

I've published the demo tableau workbook to tableau public [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/george.hart#!/vizhome/keyword_colour/Dashboard1?publish=yes)

Comment: @G Hart - This is a great approach and thank you for the really well explained response! I'm trying it out on my model today.

Comment: @G Hart - It was a great fit for what I was looking. Thank you for your help on this!